# Algorithms for generic containers in Ada

Tags: stl, ada, stl-algorithm

Is there an Ada library that implements common algorithms for generic containers, like `Delete_If`, `Count_If`, etc.?  For those who know C++, I am looking for something akin to the C++ STL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's almost certainly been superseded by `Ada.Containers` in Ada-2005/2012, you may be interested in an Ada precursor of the STL, before Stepanov converted it to C++.

This was posted today on comp.lang.ada.

If you go to [Alex Stepanov's papers](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/) and scroll down to the "Source Code" section, the third link there is to "David R. Musser and Alexander A. Stepanov: Ada Generic Library" as a zip file, unpacked, and a [readme](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/adalib/README).

As it appears to be for a VAX/VMS Ada compiler and dates from 1989, it may be of historical interest only, and there may be some effort required in even getting it to build using Gnat, let alone using it for your purposes.

Answer (score 3):

While "Questions asking us to recommend or find a…software library…are off-topic," `Ada.Containers`, described in [*§18 of the Ada Reference Manual*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-TOC.html), will likely provide the best equivalent to elements of the [*Standard Template Library*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library). Each container type uses an instance of [`Ada.Iterator_Interfaces`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-5-1.html) to `Iterate` through the container, invoking whatever predicate (find, count, etc.) is defined in your implementation of `Process`. See [*§A.18.32 Example of Container Use*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-32.html) and [*§8.3 Iterating and updating containers*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-8-3.html) for details.

Comment: This approach will support counting, but probably won’t let you delete a current item, because that would be [tampering with the cursor](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html#p90).

Comment: @SimonWright: Right; I'd use an auxiliary `Container` to collect the trash for later disposal.

Comment: What I did (using a Vector) was to reverse-loop using indexed access. Worked a treat - but wouldn’t have worked for Maps. I missed the Booch Components’ `Delete_Item_At`.